# Use of tags to send information to a function

Tags: html

I'm pretty new to HTML5 and have inherited someone else's code, which turns out not to be working.

I have a site with 8 different categories and 'add to email list' buttons, one for each category.
We use formspree to create the form code and then connect with our marketing systems. Instead of integrating 8 different forms, the previous coder added one from as a function*, then referred to that function on each of the 8 buttons.

Edit:*Its not actually a function, what is below is the only code involved.

To determine which of the categories the form came from, its meant to pass over a tag, but it's that tag that is not working and I would appreciate help on.

```
<!-- Waitlist modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="waitlist-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title heavy-text" id="modal-label">Request Access</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="contact-form" action="https://formspree.io/email@gmail.com" method="POST" >
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="full-name">Full name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full-name" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email-address">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email-address" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="incubator" name="incubator">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="ip-address" name="ip-address">
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" id="submit-form" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

The below code is for each of the 8 category's join buttons. 

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#waitlist-modal" data-id="entrepreneur" class="yellow-link">
<p class="yellow-text call-to-action" style="font-size: 0.7rem;">JOIN THE WAITLIST ➞</p>
</a>
```

As far as I understand, its meant to collect the full name and email address visibly, then the IP and the "incubator" [category] silently. All but the "incubator" tag works fine, which never passes over anything. In the links, the previous coder uses data-id="entrepreneur" [a category] for example, which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: What is the question

Comment: @Laif The question is how do I set up/fix the tags such that the function actually returns what category it came from. At the moment, I'll get back a name, email, IP but no category. The result is I don't know which of the 8 lists the customer is actually signing up for.

Comment: Welcome Adam, in the question you mention a function (in javascript I guess) and formspree use. Can you share that code? Also, can you tell us what have you tried so far and where it's failing?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto Thanks! This is the only code involved. I guess I considered the first large code block as the 'function', though I understand its not a function-function per-se. You'll have to forgive my greenness.

My issue is I fundamentally don't understand _how_ the two sets of code are meant to interact and pass over associated data. I've tried googling and reading but its not sinking in unfrtunatey.

Comment: I recommend you get familiar with dev tools like the web console (usually F12) and inspect the network IO for a better understanding.

Comment: Seems to me like you just need to understand how HTML forms work. Take a look at the MDN article to learn all about [Your first HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Your_first_HTML_form)

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto That page does not deal with my specific problem